# Elasticsearch curator not deleting old indices

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch + Kibana + File-/Metric-/Winlogbeat to summarize my logfiles.
To not fill up my HDD with tons of logs I wanted to just keep them 14 days - so I installed Curator to do this job for me.
Unfortunately Curator is not deleting any logs due to *Empty List*. I was not able to figure out why Curator thinks there is not suitable indices to delete.

My action.yml looks like

```
actions:
  1:
    action: delete_indices
    description: >-
      Delete indices older than 30 days (based on index name), for winlogbeat-
      prefixed indices. Ignore the error if the filter does not result in an
      actionable list of indices (ignore_empty_list) and exit cleanly.
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: True
      timeout_override:
      continue_if_exception: False
      disable_action: False
    filters:
    - filtertype: pattern
      kind: prefix
      value: winlogbeat-
    - filtertype: age
      source: name
      direction: older
      timestring: '%Y.%m.%d'
      unit: days
      unit_count: 14
```

The names of my Winlog indices are
*winlogbeat-7.5.2-2020.04.01-000033*
*winlogbeat-7.5.2-2020.04.02-000034*

I tried many things but the issue stayed.

Any idea what could fix my problem?

Comment: I think your filter should be `winlogbeat-*`

Comment: So far I have tried multiple wildcards - nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the only working solution for me is run curator_cli manually - althought it's done by a cronjob.

```
curator_cli --config /home/user/curator.yml delete_indices --filter_list '[{"filtertype":"age","source":"creation_date","direction":"older","timestring":"%Y.%m.%d","unit":"days","unit_count":7},{"filtertype":"pattern","kind":"prefix","value":"winlogbeat-"}]'
```